# buttons in listView not always triggered

Tags: android, listview, onclick

I have a listview and in each cell it has a RelativeLayout with 7 buttons.
before the list is scrolled all the buttons work fine (all trigger when clicked) for all visible listView items, but after listView was scrolled some items turn to not clickable (no matter which button in the item I click), and it's random, after another scroll the same item can turn clickable, and other which was before turns to not clickable.
I have noticed that it usually happens (item turns not clickable) after scrolling all the way up.
Another thing that i have noticed that seldom (after 4-5 unsuccessful clicks in a row) the button triggers a few times in a row (like it was delayed). But usually it's not happening after a number of unsuccessful clicks.

In my original code I created an arrayList of RelativeLayouts (each for listView Item), and put the arrayList into adapter. For every 7 buttons (for each cell) I set 7 ids corresponding to their's place in arraylist.
In that way I implemented the OnClick event in the main class.
Here is 3 buttons (out of 7):

```
for (int i = 0; i < EXPEND_BUTTONS.length; i++) {
            if (view.getId() == EXPEND_BUTTONS[i]) {
                handleEmojiPanel(i);
                break;
            }
            if (view.getId() == BUTTONS[i] || view.getId() == IMAGES[i]) {
                ShowTopItem item = new ShowTopItem(getActivity(), i);
                item.show();
                break;
            }
        }
```

Because of the problem I change the code.
I handled the OnClick event for the buttons in the adapter itself in the getView method (for 2 buttons only):

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        pos = position;
        Button btn = (Button) listOfObjects.get(position).getChildAt(0);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                ShowTopItem item = new ShowTopItem(getActivity(), position + listChosen);
                item.show();
            }
        });
        Button imageBtn = (Button) listOfObjects.get(position).getChildAt(2);
        imageBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                ShowTopItem item = new ShowTopItem(getActivity(), position + listChosen);
                item.show();
            }
        });
        return listOfObjects.get(position);
    }
```

I have the same result. Nothing changed.

I have looked all over the internet, and it seems that I'm the only one who encountered such issue.

Id anybody knows what can be the issue here?
If some other code is needed, please feel free to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not find the reason, but I changed ListView to ScrollView, and all works fine now.
Maybe there is some kind of bug in ListView, but in this case, I wonder why I did not find any complains regarding it.
Anyway, works perfect with ScrollView.